# How to restrict FetchedResultsController to objects in a given day

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I am trying to create a `UITableView` that populates with objects for a selected date (specifically `yesterday`, `today`, and `tomorrow`) . In my CoreData model, the entity in question as a property `date with type`Date`.

To get `yesterday`, `today`, and `tomorrow` I do this (as prescribed by [this WWDC session](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2013/227/)):

```
var today = Date()
var yesterday = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: -1, to: self.date)
var tomorrow = calendar.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: self.date)
```

and perform:

```
today = calendar.startOfDay(for: today)
yesterday = calendar.startOfDay(for: yesterday)
tomorrow = calendar.startOfDay(for: tomorrow)
```

Once I get all of the dates, I don't know what to do. Currently my fetched results controller looks like:

```
    lazy var fetchedResultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Entry> = {

        let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Entry> = Entry.fetchRequest()

        // Configure Fetch Request
        fetchRequest.sortDescriptors = [NSSortDescriptor(key: "name", ascending: true)]

        // Create Fetched Results Controller
        let fetchedResultsController = NSFetchedResultsController(fetchRequest: fetchRequest, managedObjectContext: app_delegate.persistentContainer.viewContext, sectionNameKeyPath: nil, cacheName: nil)

        // Configure Fetched Results Controller
        fetchedResultsController.delegate = self

        return fetchedResultsController
}()
```

How do I restrict the `fetchedResultsController` to one of those dates and, if possible, I do I do it using `Calendar`s method: `isDateInToday()`?

Comment: You'll want to use a predicate (`NSPredicate`) on the fetch request, but the details depend on how you want to use those dates. From yesterday to tomorrow? From yesterday to today?

Comment: It would be three separate view controllers, each one representing all the entries from yesterday, today, and yesterday respectively.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a predicate to the fetch request.

```
request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "date > %@ && date < %@", 
   today as NSDate, tomorrow as NSDate)
```

Comment: I am getting the error that my two dates (both are of type `Date`) do not conform to `CVarArg`, but when I look in the docs, `Date` and `NSDate` both conform to it. Thoughts?

Comment: Just cast to `NSDate`.